# Truffle migrate to ganache-cli (testrpc) hangs on deploying Migrations.sol

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration

I am trying to truffle migrate Metacoin to debug why Tuffle migrate is not working to testRPC/ganache-cli. It gets hung up on deploying for testRPC/ganache but if I do it from truffle develop and not specify ganache, then truffle's internal testRPC it migrates fine.

Current versions

> Truffle v4.0.4 - a development framework for Ethereum
>
> Ganache CLI v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

I am running the following sequence:

```
mkdir metacoin

cd metacoin

truffle unbox metacoin
```

Open new tab

```
ganache-cli -u 0
```

Go back to the metacoin tab

```
truffle compile

truffle migrate --reset --network development --verbose-rpc
```

The output without --verbose-rpc looks like:

> Using network 'development'.
>
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   Deploying Migrations...

With --verbose-rpc

```
       > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 1,
   >   "method": "net_version",
   >   "params": []
   > }
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "1",
 <     "id": 1
 <   }
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
   > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 2,
   >   "method": "eth_accounts",
   >   "params": []
   > }
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": [
 <       "0x006faef83e11473a09e59d2d2150209f11e216f9"
 <     ],
 <     "id": 2
 <   }
   > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 3,
   >   "method": "net_version",
   >   "params": []
   > }
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "1",
 <     "id": 3
 <   }
  Deploying Migrations...
   > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 4,
   >   "method": "net_version",
   >   "params": []
   > }
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "1",
 <     "id": 4
 <   }
   > {
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "id": 5,
   >   "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
   >   "params": [
   >     {
   >       "from": "0xdcb731f4cc8349df9ef206f3c0e46ae532239917",
   >       "gas": "0x6691b7",
   >       "gasPrice": "0x174876e800",
   >       "data": "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"
   >     }
   >   ]
   > }
```

Response from ganache-cli (with -v)

```
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410835,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x58ba5d062e2c2b14dc8b8458872afef70a9b25eb",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410836,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x58ba5d062e2c2b14dc8b8458872afef70a9b25eb",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410835,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410836,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410844,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x15528fc3cff56b4667f988c699ec5983030ce841",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410838,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xf45ae1668bf2a6f7175a0795384b2059789e84a5",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410839,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xf45ae1668bf2a6f7175a0795384b2059789e84a5",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410841,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xe4753e4dff52c272ac3f8037bc1f218e768ac66d",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410844,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410838,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410841,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410839,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410848,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x11f2915576dc51dffb246959258e8fe5a1913161",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410850,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xc69e35474199292ab39d047490963bd5b01fb73e",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410845,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x15528fc3cff56b4667f988c699ec5983030ce841",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410848,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410850,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410845,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410853,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x0327ff417aa111b61bed5f39e77946b38d6592b3",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410854,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x0327ff417aa111b61bed5f39e77946b38d6592b3",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410853,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410854,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410858,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x58ba5d062e2c2b14dc8b8458872afef70a9b25eb",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410859,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x58ba5d062e2c2b14dc8b8458872afef70a9b25eb",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410858,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410859,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410861,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xf45ae1668bf2a6f7175a0795384b2059789e84a5",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410865,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xe4753e4dff52c272ac3f8037bc1f218e768ac66d",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410864,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xe4753e4dff52c272ac3f8037bc1f218e768ac66d",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410861,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410865,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410864,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410871,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x11f2915576dc51dffb246959258e8fe5a1913161",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410867,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x15528fc3cff56b4667f988c699ec5983030ce841",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410868,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x15528fc3cff56b4667f988c699ec5983030ce841",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410871,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410867,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410868,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410874,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0xc69e35474199292ab39d047490963bd5b01fb73e",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getBalance
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410876,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x0327ff417aa111b61bed5f39e77946b38d6592b3",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getBalance",
   >   "external": true
   > }
eth_getTransactionCount
   > {
   >   "id": 6578289014410877,
   >   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >   "params": [
   >     "0x0327ff417aa111b61bed5f39e77946b38d6592b3",
   >     "latest"
   >   ],
   >   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount",
   >   "external": true
   > }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410874,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410876,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
 <   {
 <     "id": 6578289014410877,
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "result": "0x0"
 <   }
```

I tried reinstalling both truffle and testRPC/ganache-cli, I also noticed that the truffle migration logs show that it is getting an eth_account that I haven't seen before and is not apart of Ganache-cli/testRPC.

I have no additional nodes running (geth, parity, private chain etc.)
Just two weeks I was migrating large contracts to private chains and had no problem so this wasn't always here.

Any thoughts?

Best,
Sam

Comment: Did you try launching with `ganache-cli` without any parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found out the reason it wasn't migrating was that Parity has a few super well hidden processes that didnt show up when I did `ps -a` ; After finding that parity process and killing it, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I found a hidden instance of ganache, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by reducing the gas limit in the truffle-config.js to the permissible limit in ganache

Answer (score 0):

For me it was having the `HDWalletProvider` set with the wrong mnemonic

```
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:7545"),
```

Updating to the correct mnemonic with fund inside the wallet, such as the one ganache generated with loaded addresses, or removing the HDWalletProvider line to simply fall back to the default account worked.